# Req. query doesn't pass

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to pull data from a document containing a logged-in user from the MongoDB database. However, req. the query doesn't seem to pass.

```js
case "GET": {
  const { userName } = req.query;
  const users = await db
    .collection("USERS")
    .find({ user: { $in: [userName] } })
    .toArray();
  res.json(users);
  break;
}
```

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/usersAPI`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  let users = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { users },
  };
}
```

Comment: You are passing `{ users }` but extracting `{ userName }`

Comment: I do not understand?

Comment: In the frontend controller, where do you pass the prop "userName" to the request?

Comment: I do not know how. I'm stuck.

Comment: You're not passing any query parameter when making the request to the API route. The URL should look like: `http://localhost:3000/api/usersAPI?userName=value`.

Comment: Also, you should not be calling an internal API route from inside `getStaticProps`, you can write server-side code directly in it. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#write-server-side-code-directly.